# How to implement toggle effect with key combination < CTRL + Q > for Jquery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, keycode

I have JQuery UI Dialog opening on pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> using the following code..

```
$(window).keydown(function (e){
     if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 81){
         $('<div><center>Download the files now?</center></div>').dialog({
            title: '<b>Download</b>', 
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 400, 
            width: 800,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function(){  
                    // Code to download the Files
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                "Close": function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
     }
});
```

But how can i close the dialog on pressing them again? I want to implement the toggle effect for the dialog with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like that?

```
var myDialog = null;

$(window).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 81) {
        if (myDialog != null) {
            myDialog.dialog('close');
            myDialog = null;
        } else {
            var markup = '<div><center>Download the files now?</center></div>';
            myDialog = $(markup).dialog({
                title: '<b>Download</b>', 
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: true,
                height: 400, 
                width: 800,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function(){  
                        // Code to download the Files
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    "Close": function(){
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/95w4m/

Comment: Not working.. The window is opened with CTRL + Q but is not closed when pressed again.

Comment: You have to change `if (myDialog == null) {` to `if (myDialog != null) {` otherwise this will yeld an error.